# Jenkins: avoid using credentials in groovy string interpolation not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, interpolation, credentials

I'm trying to apply best practices to my jenkins pipelines, so I'm trying to apply the recommendation that Groovy string interpolation should never be used with credentials

First I'm executing in my pipeline as recommended in [Jenkins documentation - interpolation of sensitive vars](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables), so I use single quotes in my script:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-docker-user', passwordVariable: 'docker_pwd', usernameVariable: 'docker_usr')]) {

dcheckScriptResult = sh label: 'Retrieving image', script: ''' docker login -u $docker_usr -p $docker_pwd $dockerRegistry ''', returnStatus: true 

echo "dcheckScriptResult = $dcheckScriptResult" 
}
```

But I'm getting as a result:

```
04:59:04  + docker login -u **** -p ****
04:59:04  Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

Now I try as it is considered wrong (double quotes):

```
        dcheckScriptResult = sh label: 'Retrieving image', script: """ docker login -u $docker_usr -p $docker_pwd $dockerRegistry """, returnStatus: true

        echo "dcheckScriptResult = $dcheckScriptResult"
```

And it works...but with the warning about using the groovy interpolation:

```
05:11:54  Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
05:11:54         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [docker_pwd, docker_usr]
05:11:54         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
05:11:54  + docker login -u **** -p **** myrepository.mycompany
05:11:54  WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/ccloud/.docker/config.json.
05:11:54  Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
05:11:54  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
05:11:54  
05:11:54  Login Succeeded
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I missed the error message. The diff in first comparing to  second captured docker command is missing registry address. I think you have just to make `dockerRegistry` available as environment variable.

Comment: thanks for the idea @daggett, that was the issue the `dockerRegistry` variable was missing.  I solved it taking it out of the single quotes like this:

`dcheckScriptResult = sh label: 'Retrieving image', script: ''' echo $docker_pwd | docker login -u $docker_user --password-stdin ''' + dockerRegistry , returnStatus: true `